# Understanding Parboiled2's '~' Combinator

Tags: shapeless, parboiled2

Looking at the [parboiled2](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2) section, `Rule Combinators and Modifiers`:

[image]

I don't understand the `a`, `b`, and then `a ~ b` diagram.

So far I've found the documentation straightforward. But *I* am a bit lost here.

Can you please explain each block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the definition of `Rule`:

```
class Rule[-I <: HList, +O <: HList]
```

The documentation you linked gives more explanation, but essentially `I` is the input to the Rule and `O` is the output of the Rule. The colon notation can be a little confusing. `parboiled2` uses a stack to manage the state. Just remember that the types in the colon lists (`HList`) are produced/pushed from left to right, and consumed/popped from right to left. In the `HList` `A:B:C`, `C` is the top of the stack, and has to be consumed first.

`~` runs one rule then the next. So in the first example `a` of type `Rule[, A]` consumes nothing and 'produces' an `A`, while `b` of type `Rule[, B]` consumes nothing and 'produces' a `B`. It makes sense then, that if you ran `a` followed by `b`, you would produce an `A` followed by a `B`. The resulting type is `Rule[, A:B]`.

Things become much more complicated when you add inputs. You need to make sure that the types produced by `a` (or whatever the first rule is) are the types that `b` is going to consume. `~` is just like function composition. If we want to compose `g` and `f` to get `g . f`, we need to be sure that the output of `f` is the same type as the input of `g`.

Let's look at the third example in the table.

- `a` has type `Rule[A, B:C]`
- `b` has type `Rule[D:B:C, E:F]`

When we run `a` an `A` is consumed from the stack, a `B` is added to the stack, and a `C` is added to the stack. Then `b` is run, first it consumes the `C`, then the `B`, then it consumes a `D` off the stack. To be in the right place at the right time, that `D` would need to be under the `A` that `a` consumed. `b` would then produce an `E` then an `F`.

In total, we consumed a `D` and an `A`. The `B` and `C` don't count because they were produced and consumed internally to the rule. After consuming `D` and `A`, we leave `E` and `F` on the stack. So, the type of `a ~ b` is `Rule[D:A, E:F]`.

The fourth example in the README gives an example where `a` produces the wrong types for `b` to consume. In that case `a ~ b` is illegal.